# Facebook application dialog doesn't show premissions

Tags: facebook, oauth

I created an application to use Facebook-Connect and marked only the email as needed user permissions.
On on the preview screen it asks "Your basic info" & "email".

But, when I try to register to the application it only state that it need "Your basic info" 
and not asking about the email. And indeed it doesn't take the reveal the user email to the application.

Comment: We need to see some code to help you.

Comment: What kind of code? It's the facebook application registration form.

Comment: You need to pass a `scope` parameter to the login dialog.

Comment: what do you mean? I'm using passport.js. And the same code work perfectly with another application.

Comment: ok, found it thanks! it was the scope indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was lack of scope.

For more details about how to do it with passportjs see: [passport-facebook](http://passportjs.org/guide/facebook/).